# How to find attribute on method called by lambda expression?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, attributes

For various reasons, I need to run code that looks like this:

```
public class MethodRunner {
     public T RunMethod<T>(Func<T> method) {
          method.Invoke();
     }
}
```

I have a class with a custom attribute that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
     [MyAttribute("somevalue")]
     public string SayHello(string message) {
         Console.WriteLine(message);
         return message;
     }
}
```

I can then call `MyClass.SayHello` by writing

```
var runner = new MethodRunner();
var myClass = new MyClass();

runner.RunMethod(() => myClass.SayHello("hello!"));
```

What I would like to do is, in the body of `MethodRunner.RunMethod`, use reflection to see the parameter of the `MyAttribute` class on `MyClass.SayHello`. However, I'm not sure how to get there. All I can see using reflection is the lambda expression itself, not its contents.

Comment: Short answer: You can't (do it easily). If you can say what problem you're trying to solve instead, it will be easy to answer.

Comment: It's a **lambda** expression (yes - `b` before `d` - not just *lamba* as you spelled it twice)

Comment: Believe, you have to use Expression instead of Func. That will get you a lot more access to the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy if you are able to change `Func<T>` into an `Expression<Func<T>>` instead.

Here is an example if that is possible:

```
public class MethodRunner {
     public T RunMethod<T>(Expression<Func<T>> method) {
          var body = method.Body as MethodCallExpression;
          if (body == null)
              throw new NotSupportedException();

           var attributes = body.Method.GetCustomAttributes(false);

           // Do something with Attributes

           return expression.Compile().Invoke();
     }
}
```

The difficulty when just using `Func<T>` with `() =>` is that the compiler will generate an actual method. As far as I am aware, you cannot grab "lines" of code out of a method. The one way around this which does not help you since you have parameters is to use `RunMethod(myClass.SayHello)` instead of `RunMethod(() => myClass.SayHello)`.